# ToolStripButton text gets cut off in ContextMenuStrip

Tags: .net, winforms, contextmenustrip, toolstripbutton

I am instantiating my own `ToolStripButton` and adding it to a `ContextMenuStrip`. It pops up but the text gets cut off:

```
string[] layouts = new string[]{"Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"};
List<ToolStripButton> items = new List<ToolStripButton>();
foreach (string layout in layouts)
{
    ToolStripButton item = new ToolStripButton(layout, image, LayoutClicked);
    item.AutoSize = true;
    items.Add(item);
}
layoutMenus.Items.Clear();
layoutMenus.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
layoutMenus.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
```

Any idea why the text is getting cut off as the `AutoSize` property is `true`?

Comment: In my case I could replace `ToolStripButton` with `ToolStripMenuItem` to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curious; I can reproduce this... a reall oddity (for me) is that setting the menu's `.Width` fixes it... but setting it **to anything** (it seems to ignore the value completely):

```
layoutMenus.Width = 800; // could be 20, or 100 and would appear the same
```

See if that works. It does for me, even though it makes no real sense.

Even:

```
layoutMenus.Width++;
layoutMenus.Width--;
```

leaves enough space, but

```
layoutMenus.Width = layoutMenus.Width;
```

doesn't (presumably it checks for non-changes and ignores whatever side-effects the above has).

Comment: For me, in order for dynamic menu item modification to work, I needed to use Chin Lin's comment together with yours: `menuItem.AutoSize = false; menuItem.AutoSize = true; menuItem.Width++;`

Answer (score 3):

After some refactoring of a previously working context menu implementation, I have been facing the same problem. Like @PeteBaughman, I was not able to fix this by changing the `ContextMenuStrip.Width` - the width in fact did not change (also `ContextMenuStrip.MaximumSize` was not speficied: `(0,0)`).

Adding an invisible item as Pete suggested did the trick. After a few more experiments I have found **another workaround**: A call to `ContextMenuStrip.PerformLayout()` resulted in the expected behavior.

(Calling `SuspendLayout`and `ResumeLayout` before and after adding the items did not work.)

---

**Update:** The real problem might be, that a `ToolStripButton` is added to a `ContextMenuStrip` which would normally create a `ToolStripMenuItem` when called like this:

```
contextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Hello world"); // Returns a ToolStripMenuItem
```

I was able to omit the call to `PerformLayout()` after creating items of the right kind.

Answer (score 2):

2 Years Later, I've run into the same issue.  I didn't have MaxSize set and touching the Width property didn't help either.  My ContextMenuStrip only contained one item - a grayed out button that said "Not Supported".  It got truncated down to "Not Supp".

I ended up having to add a dummy item to the end of the ContextMenuStrip and set its visibility to False.  Then, the ContextMenuStrip was wide enough to show the first item that I actually cared about showing.

Link [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/42335e7c-f1c7-441c-af43-7c11530cc6d3/)

Comment: Adding dummy item worked for me. `dummy.Width` must be set. All dropdown items will be of that width.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Tried all these things, and it turned out there the `MaxSize` is set by mistake, like `(200, 0)`. Reset it to `(0,0)` fix the problem.

Comment: Did you mean `ContextMenuStrip.MaximumSize`?

Answer (score 1):

To add a bit of detail to the symptom: in my case, it seems that the issue only occurs when there is just one item in the context menu. With multiple items, the width seems to be set correctly.

And calling `ContextMenuStrip.PerformLayout` fixed this one for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem. I want to add checkbox to the menu item list. In order to do that, I need to add the checkbox to a ToolStripControlHost and then add the ToolStripControlHost to the ToolStripMenuItem object. The name of the last checkbox always get truncated by 3 characters. My solution is to toggle the AutoSize of the last item host as below:

```
Dim chkbox As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox()
chkbox.Text = "xxxxx"
Dim tshost As ToolStripControlHost = New ToolStripControlHost(chkbox)
tsmiAssemblySpecificTools.DropDownItems.Add(tshost)
                    tshost.AutoSize = False
                    tshost.AutoSize = True
```

The AutoSize toggle has to be done after the host item added to the list.

Comment: Setting the autosize off and on again helped, but it only works on first render. If I update the context menu items at some later time, and apply this same fix, then it doesn't work.